# How to add as many elements as i want to an array list by an input?

Tags: java, arraylist, input, while-loop

How to add as many elements as I want to an array list - *with only one insert operation*?

I want to add 5 Items to a buy list with *one* input. And then I want to print the 5 items out.

This is what I have done now:

```
package paket1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Class2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;

        while (i != 5) {

            String Eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add Einkaufsliste");

            ArrayList<String> einkaufsListe = new ArrayList<>();

            einkaufsListe.add(Eingabe);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to declare your list before the loop, and increment `i` inside the loop .

Comment: Thak you @Arnaud. That solved it

Answer (score 1):

Each time your iteration runs, you are creating a new, empty list, and adding one element to it. But this loop will never finish, because `i` is never incremented, and will always be `0`. The correct code would look like this:

```
int i = 0;
List<String> einkaufsListe = new ArrayList<>();
while (i <= 5) {
    String eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add Einkaufsliste");
    einkaufsListe.add(eingabe);
    i++;
}
```

And then you will have to print it as well.

Comment: This code is not compilable! But logically - correct

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to extract this logic into separate method, that retrieves required list. If you want to use `ArrayList`, do not forget to set initial size.

```
public static List<String> gibAlleEinkaufe(int insgesamt) {
    List<String> einkaufsListe = new ArrayList<>(insgesamt);

    for(int i = 0; i < insgesamt; i++)
        einkaufsListe.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add Einkaufsliste"));

    return einkaufsListe;
}
```